# Parallel programming fortran, problems with a hello program

Tags: cygwin, mpi, gfortran, openmpi

I have problems with this basic program:

!Fortran example

```
program hello

implicit none 

include 'mpif.h'  ! If I try 'use mpi' the console don't find this module.

integer :: rank, size, ierror, tag, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
   
call MPI_INIT(ierror)

call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierror)

call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror)

print*, 'node', rank, ': Hello world'

call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)

end program hello
```

---

When I compile it, I get these errors:

```
$ mpirun -np 1 hello

[DESKTOP-SLDH1SC:00140] PMIX ERROR: INIT in file /pub/devel/openmpi/v4.0/openmpi-4.0.5-

1.x86_64/src/openmpi-4.0.5/opal/mca/pmix/pmix3x/pmix/src/mca/gds/ds21/gds_ds21_lock_pthread.c at line 188

[DESKTOP-SLDH1SC:00140] PMIX ERROR: SUCCESS in file /pub/devel/openmpi/v4.0/openmpi-4.0.5-

1.x86_64/src/openmpi-4.0.5/opal/mca/pmix/pmix3x/pmix/src/mca/common/dstore/dstore_base.c at line 2450

[DESKTOP-SLDH1SC:00140] PMIX ERROR: INIT in file /pub/devel/openmpi/v4.0/openmpi-4.0.5-

1.x86_64/src/openmpi-4.0.5/opal/mca/pmix/pmix3x/pmix/src/mca/gds/ds12/gds_ds12_lock_pthread.c at line 138

[DESKTOP-SLDH1SC:00140] PMIX ERROR: SUCCESS in file /pub/devel/openmpi/v4.0/openmpi-4.0.5-

1.x86_64/src/openmpi-4.0.5/opal/mca/pmix/pmix3x/pmix/src/mca/common/dstore/dstore_base.c at line 2450

[DESKTOP-SLDH1SC:00141] PMIX ERROR: ERROR in file /pub/devel/openmpi/v4.0/openmpi-4.0.5-

1.x86_64/src/openmpi-4.0.5/opal/mca/pmix/pmix3x/pmix/src/mca/gds/ds12/gds_ds12_lock_pthread.c at line 168

 node           0 : Hello world

[DESKTOP-SLDH1SC:00140] [[39760,0],0] unable to open debugger attach fifo
```

---

What's wrong?

Finally, what's the difference between mpi and omp_lib?

Comment: Please understand that OpenMP and MPI are two completely different things. They do not have anything in common whatsoever. `omp_lib` is from OpenMP, `mpi` is from MPI.

Comment: @Vladimir F. Ok. Thanks so much for the info. Can I use either of both with cygwin? I install the packages for OpenMP and mpi ms. I can use OpenMP but I can't use mpi module, despite I set the environment variable. I would like to use mpi, instead of OpenMP because I found a excellent tutorial for this one.

Comment: How did you install OpenMPI?

Comment: what is the output of `tail  /etc/pmix-mca-params.conf/` ? and of  `cygcheck -cd |grep openmpi` ?

Comment: Ok, I don't know how to install in Windows the compress file that I download from the website. But with OMP I have no problems. Thanks both for the help.